# Manage Auto-renewable in-app purchase and consumable in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, auto-renewable

I am working in an app which uses 3 in-app product

1. Monthly subscription (Auto-renewable)
2. Yearly subscription (Auto-renewable)
3. Lifetime subscription (Consumable)

The app has a feature that a logged in user can add other app user's accounts to his account and can switch to their account.
So, a logged in user can buy all 3 above types of in-app products but he can buy only lifetime subscription for others (if he switched to others account) with the same apple account. That is why Lifetime subscription is of Consumable type.
Monthly and Yearly Subscription belongs to same subscription group as they both are auto-renewable type.

My doubt here is,

If logged in user buys a Yearly/Monthly subscription first which is Auto-renewable type that means it renews or make payment automatically after it expires monthly or yearly.
Suppose after buying Yearly subscription and then he likes the app and now buys a lifetime subscription,

1. Will both Yearly subscription and lifetime subscription will
   continue simultaneously? That means along with lifetime
   subscription, yearly subscription will continue to charge every
   year?
2. or will Yearly subscription cancel right after lifetime subscription
   is made?
3. or will apple accept the lifetime request and after 1 year it will
   cancel yearly subscription to renew itself automatically and
   activates lifetime subscription.

What I want, is point 3. The lifetime subscription should not renew after 1 year and lifetime subscription should continue. If it is going to renew, is there any way to programmatically cancel the previous (Yearly/Monthly) subscription?

I want the customer should not be double paying for the app. Customer must have only one subscription activated at a time and he must be able to make lifetime subscription purchase for other app users with same apple account.

How best can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using auto renewing subscription then you will need to tell the user to explicitly cancel their subscription if they purchase the “lifetime” access product. It won’t be cancelled automatically and you can’t do it. You might want to consider using non-renewing subscriptions and prompt the user to renew manually as required

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, I too think, app need to inform user while making lifetime subscription purchase. Non-renewing is not a good idea as per business perpective.